# Writing a function that detects a generic member

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

With C++20 it is now possible to write a template function `detect_foo`, which will return whether a template argument is a structure with a member called `foo`.

Example:

```
consteval bool detect_foo(auto&& arg) {
  if constexpr(requires { arg.foo; }) {
    // arg has a "foo" member
    return true;
  } else {
    // arg does not
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Thus, we have genericity on the left side of the `.` operator: in `arg.foo`, `arg` can be generic.

My question is: how can the `foo` part be made generic, e.g. do we have a non-macro way to write a `detect` function which would have an API not too far from this:

```
bool has_the_member = detect(some_struct, name_of_a_member);
```

e.g.

```
struct foo { int value; } a_foo;
struct bar { int value; } a_bar;

detect(a_foo, /* some magic incantation to refer to "value" */);
detect(a_bar, /* should be the same incantation than for a_foo */);
```

Comment: It's impossible, and I'm not sure why you need it. You can just use `requires`, without wrapping it in functions.

Comment: `constexpr auto has_the_member = requires { some_struct.name_of_a_member; };`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat my actual business logic on whether the member is here or not is more complicated than just true / false, and I don't want to repeat it for each member (e.g. N types, `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, may have M optional fields, `name`, `value`, `min`, `max` - I want to perform the same logic for each case of the `type ⨯ field` product and only write that logic once, not once for each field)

Comment: I suggest adding this to the question.

Comment: That would go against http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `detect` function, because you can just use `requires`.

> have M optional fields ... want to perform the same logic ... and only write that logic once

The only way of passing around a "name of a member" that comes to mind is using a lambda (or a function) that returns said member:

```
auto get_foo = [](auto &&obj) -> decltype(decltype(obj)(obj).foo) {return decltype(obj)(obj).foo;};
```

Note the explicitly specified return type, which gives us SFINAE.
Note that you have to repeat the member name twice. This asks for a macro to generate those lambdas.

You still don't need a `detect` function, and can use `requires` with the lambda directly in your code. Example:

```
void print_member(const auto &obj, auto member)
{
    if constexpr (requires{member(obj);})
        std::cout << member(obj) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "No such member.\n";
}

struct A {int foo = 1;};
struct B {int bar = 1;};

int main()
{
    print_member(A{}, get_foo); // `1`
    print_member(B{}, get_foo); // `No such member.`
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I had tried (and failed) with lambdas as I was missing the explicit return type for SFINAE.

Comment: Managed to remove the name duplication in the lambda: `[](auto &&obj) -> decltype(decltype(obj)(obj).x, void()) {}`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Yeah, but you can't actually access the member with this lambda.